Are hardware benchmark results copyrighted?
Let's say a content creator benchmarks a piece of hardware (for example, a graphics card). Is the resulting number of that benchmark copyrighted or can I use this number (not talking about the video/article that described testing method or similar)?

Whether it is or not does not change the fact that you should probably give a source and link back to the result, as a courtesy both to the original author and to your readers (who may want to get more details about the methodology etc.).

Feist Publications, Inc., v. Rural Telephone Service Co., 499 U.S. 340 (1991)
Facts, such as a particular test score or phone numbers, are not copyrightable and do not give anyone exclusive rights. Or to quote SCOTUS in their unanimous decision:

Held: Rural's white pages are not entitled to copyright, and therefore Feist's use of them does not constitute infringement. Pp. 499 U. S. 344-364.
(a) Article I, § 8, cl. 8, of the Constitution mandates originality as a prerequisite for copyright protection. The constitutional requirement necessitates independent creation plus a modicum of creativity. Since facts do not owe their origin to an act of authorship, they are not original, and thus are not copyrightable. Although a compilation of facts may possess the requisite originality because the author typically chooses which facts to include, in what order to place them, and how to arrange the data so that readers may use them effectively, copyright protection extends only to those components of the work that are original to the author, not to the facts themselves. This fact/expression dichotomy severely limits the scope of protection in fact-based works. Pp. 499 U. S. 344-351.
(b) The Copyright Act of 1976 and its predecessor, the Copyright Act of 1909, leave no doubt that originality is the touchstone of copyright protection in directories and other fact-based works. The 1976 Act explains that copyright extends to "original works of authorship," 17 U.S.C. § 102(a), and that there can be no copyright in facts, § 102(b).
A compilation is not copyrightable per se, but is copyrightable only if its facts have been "selected, coordinated, or arranged in such a way that the resulting work as a whole constitutes an original work of authorship." § 101 (emphasis added). Thus, the statute envisions that some ways of selecting, coordinating, and arranging data are not sufficiently original to trigger copyright protection. Even a compilation that is copyrightable receives only limited protection, for the copyright does not extend to facts contained in the compilation. § 103(b). Lower courts that adopted a "sweat of the brow" or "industrious collection" test -- which extended a compilation's copyright protection beyond selection and arrangement to the facts themselves -- misconstrued the 1909 Act and eschewed the fundamental axiom of copyright law that no one may copyright facts or ideas. Pp. 499 U. S. 351-361.
(c) Rural's white pages do not meet the constitutional or statutory requirements for copyright protection. While Rural has a valid copyright in the directory as a whole because it contains some forward text and some original material in the yellow pages, there is nothing original in Rural's white pages. The raw data are uncopyrightable facts, and the way in which Rural selected, coordinated, and arranged those facts is not original in any way. Rural's selection of listings -- subscribers' names, towns, and telephone numbers -- could not be more obvious, and lacks the modicum of creativity necessary to transform mere selection into copyrightable expression. In fact, it is plausible to conclude that Rural did not truly "select" to publish its subscribers' names and telephone numbers, since it was required to do so by state law. Moreover, there is nothing remotely creative about arranging names alphabetically in a white pages directory. It is an age-old practice, firmly rooted in tradition and so commonplace that it has come to be expected as a matter of course. Pp. 499 U. S. 361-364.
916 F.2d 718 (CA 10 1990), reversed.


Note that this decision applies in the USA. In some jurisdictions, the "sweat of the brow", "skill & labour" or database rights can apply to a suitable large datasets, although probably not in a way to affect the original question.

Note also that there may be issues of trademark and/or personality rights to consider, depending on what OP means by "use." You can probably advertise a benchmark result in neutral terms. You probably cannot present the benchmark as an endorsement (unless an endorsement was actually published as such).

@Kevin "XYZ tested this with a score of ABC" is a fact, not an endorsement. "XYZ liked our product" would be an endorsement (and might be false advertisement)

@origimbo "sweat of the brow" or "database rights" only exists for compilations of facts, not a single fact. You can always cite "XYZ has score X in Database ABC", which is generally allowable

Benchmarks may be different from the mere collection of facts, because the benchmark results (i.e. facts) couldn't exist if not for some "sweat of the brow" of the person(s) designing and executing the benchmarks. Whereas the person's name, address, or telephone number exist regardless of the white pages' publisher's efforts, the benchmark results don't. Wouldn't that affect the stance?

@mustaccio they don't. It takes equipment and work to measure the height of a mountain, but there is no artistic choice in the number "1234 m" that comes out at the end. The benchmark is, by its definition, the result of some very complex calculations. The actual calculation formula and program is under copyright as it is some artistic expression, the outcome of a particular setup, as a simple grade, is not.

What about the naming of stars (and such) by bodies organized or incidentally doing that when new ones are found, the name is a choice designed and designated. When does it become a fact? The first time used?

@civitas There is no copyright in names, (US) and copyrighting names or common words would be absurd (UK) The question thus is moot. Plus, there is no creativity in designations like XO-5, D 95086 or η Tauri A.

@origimbo: You're not wrong but this is treading into plagiarism territory more so than "fact copyright". For any created work, facts or no facts, there remains to be the question whether a second author of a second similar piece did in fact copy the first article's content or created the second article independent of the first one. What you're alluding to here with "sweat of the brow" is a broader plagiarism protection.

@Trish "XYZ liked our product" is not an endorsement. Quoting XYZ to have said "I like [product]" would be an endorsement, because it comes from the mouth of XYZ. Comparatively, "XYZ liked our product" is shorthand for "XYZ indicated that they like our product", which is an observable fact (and not necessarily reflecting today's reality, e.g. if XYZ changed their mind since then).

@civitas By the very nature of what a name is, it is inherently in the public domain.

Accepting that the facts are non-coyrightable (although their presentation might be), but it is common for them to be provided under an explicit NDA. Notorious here were IBM mainframes, where discussing performance etc. contravened the usage agreement.
